# Let $a, b, c \in \mathbb{Z}$. Show: If $a \shortmid b$ and $a \shortmid (b+c),$ then $a \shortmid c.$ Hint: $c = (b+c)-b.$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

I'm working on my discrete math homework, and I come to this problem:
Let $a, b, c \in \mathbb{Z}$. Show: If $a \shortmid b$ and $a \shortmid (b+c),$ then $a \shortmid c.$ Hint: $c = (b+c)-b.$
I've been trying to figure out something with the definition of divides, but am having trouble seeing how that can lead to the outcome that I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There exists $m, n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, s.t. $b = a\cdot m$ and $b+c = a \cdot n$. Hence, $c = (b+c) - b = a \cdot (n - m)$, where $n - m$ must be a positive integer. Therefore, we proved $a \shortmid c$.

Comment: Why are you assuming that $m, n$ are positive?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you solve this,

Here given that $a|b$ and $a|(b+c)$.

So by definition we can write ,

$$b=m\cdot a ~~~\text{ and }$$

$$(b+c)=n\cdot a  ~\text{, for some } ~~~~m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$$.

Now let's take subtraction of both equations we have,

$(b+c)-b = n\cdot a - m\cdot a$

$\therefore  c= (n-m)\cdot a$  $~~~$ Where , $n-m \in \mathbb{Z}$

$\therefore c= p\cdot a$ , where $n-m=p \in \mathbb{Z}$

So, By definition we have $a|c.$

Hence, Proved.